# Refreshing $(document).ready()

Tags: jquery

I'm building a web application, and for some time it has been bugging me, that when I load HTML into my page by ajax, I need to refresh my functions within $(document).ready().

Let's for example say I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#searchInput').keyup(function () {
        // Do something
    });

});
```

However my input field with id="searchInput" is not loaded when the DOM is loaded - it is being loaded later on using an ajax, when the user clicks a specific element.
Now my input field with id="searchInput" is loaded, but the keyup(function) does not listen to #searchInput since it was not loaded in the original DOM.

For now, my only solution has been to do like this:

```
function loadEvents() {
    $('#searchInput').keyup(function () {
        // Do something
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadEvents();
});
```

And then on ajax succes:

```
succes:
    function() {
        loadEvents();
    }
```

This works... But I can't help to think that there is a smarter way...

I have multiple functions within my loadEvents(), and for me I does not seem like the best solution to reload all functions every time an ajax call is successful?

Of course I could then make many different ajax calls, which on ajax succes executes specific functions needed, but then I will have to create many different ajax functions.

Any better solutions out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to consolidate all your success callback code in one place

```
$(selector).ajaxSuccess(function(event,xhr,options){
     //DO YOUR STUFF HERE
});
```

See more about it at http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/